# Seeking xyz basemap catalog?

Tags: carto, basemap, google-earth-pro, odyssey-js

I've been using cartodb odyssey.js for a couple of months and the https://khms1.googleapis.com/kh?v=152&hl=es-ES&x={x}&y={y}&z={z} XYZ basemap has sufficed so far. However, I'm working on a location that doesn't seem to be covered beyond zoom 13 and the resolution is not good at zoom 13.

Is there a list of possible alternatives out there?

The current Google Earth data is super high resolution but I can't find it as a basemap. I've also tried the Nokia Day option but the area I'm looking at is cloud covered.

---

This is the map story I've made.  http://www.burdgis.com/blog/map/opwall-cusuco-national-park/  There's some great answers below but I can't find anything that allows me to zoom in close enough without cloud cover problems. Unsurprising as the park is a cloud forest. The current google earth imagery is very good but short of making my own tiles from that none of the free options are satisfactory right now. It would need to be satellite imagery rather than hillshade etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a cool tool that lets you check out different basemap providers and gives you the references to the tiles for your code.  It's based on leaflet but could still be helpful to you. [leaflet basemap provider demo](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)

Answer (score 2):

ESRI has some great base maps: [ESRI Base maps](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/maps/maps-and-map-layers) (check licensing)

Mapbox has some great base maps: [Mapbox Base Maps](https://www.mapbox.com/data-platform/) (paid service)

Mapquest has some great base maps: [Mapquest Base Maps](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map)

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS with QMetaTiles to generate XYZ/TMS or MBTILES. DATA from local and or both online data
I like Mapzen OpenStreetMap served data. https://mapzen.com/products/maps/

QGIS allows you.to connect to an XYZ Source or WMTS or use open layers plugin to add other basemaps